# RetryTemplate vs @RetryableTopic

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am trying to understand the similarities and distinctions between RetryTemplate and @RetryableTopic.

RetryTemplate is defined inside KafkaListenerContainerFactory itself and @RetryableTopic annotation is added together with @KafkaListener. Is this more of a stylistic difference or do they have two different purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RetryTemplate` in the container factory is deprecated because the error handlers now support backoff and exception classification.

The difference between normal retries (template or error handlers) is that a retried record blocks consumption of other records in the partition until the record is successfully processed or discarded. This is important if strict ordering is required.

`@RetryableTopic` on the other hand is non-blocking retry in that the failed record is moved to a different topic each time it fails. This allows processing of subsequent records during retries. Useful if strict ordering is not important.

See **Non-Blocking Retries** https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.4-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#retry-topic

Comment: Is there any downside or unpredictability that can be caused by using `RetryTemplate` and `@RetryableTopic` together? Can one supersede/override another if used together?

Currently, our WIP project is hoping to use `RetryTemplate` to retry a few times before moving the events to RetryableTopic. I am not sure if that's a best practice; mostly anxious if these two can play along without interfering with each other. we are on spring-kakfka, 2.7.x

Comment: I don't see any problems as long as you don't use stateful retry (but then you need to ensure the aggregate backoff won't exceed the `max.poll.interval.ms`). The upcoming 2.8.4 release allows a combination of blocking and non-blocking retries where we fall back to non-blocking after the blocking retries are exhausted. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/a7621a101ecf8382224358323878d5fde21cb8bf

Comment: Here is the documentation for this upcoming feature: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.4-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#retry-topic-combine-blocking

Comment: Updated url for Non-Blocking Retries : https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retry-topic

Answer (score 6):

Those are different approaches to retrying failed processing records.

The `RetryTemplate` approach has been [deprecated](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/59f25508cfc90e14e3f3a1dbd65bd73515f33385/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/config/AbstractKafkaListenerContainerFactory.java#L185) - it relies on retrying the record in memory, which could trigger partition rebalancing if the total time of the retrials is greater than the `max.poll.interval.ms` property.

You can use a [DefaultErrorHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.4-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#default-eh) to achieve `blocking retrials` - if record processing fails, the framework will seek to that offset and receive the record again - this reduces the chance of a rebalance being triggered while waiting for the retrials compared to the previous method. No other records will be processed until this record either succeeds or exhausts the retrials, which is important if you need to keep record ordering.

The [@RetryableTopic](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.4-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#retry-topic) approach uses one or more topics to achieve `non-blocking retrials`, meaning if one record fails, it'll be forwarded to another topic for the retrials, and the main topic will continue processing the remaining records. In this approach, you lose ordering guarantees in exchange for not having failed record processing retrials slow down other records' processing.

Comment: Tomaz - looks like we answered this at around the same time; please see the comments on my answer; thanks.